# How to structure the css files in reactjs in a way that it follows the concept of component separation

Tags: reactjs

I have a question,

I am working on a project which is written in react.
Everything is based on component in react so based on my understanding everything including css files should be defined in a related component itself this way if we remove the component from the project every related file will be removed so far so good.

However consider this case:

```
.size{
   font-size:20px;
}
```

as you can see there are many cases as above which can be used in different components. So we want to put all the css files into the related components then we should either replicate the same css definition in different places or for these kind of scenarios we can have a shared folder out of the components. Is there any rule or guideline how to structure the css files in a react project in the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is any established way to organized shared css but let me offer some observations.

If you have an `App` component that imports an `App.css`. Any of the components used within this app will have access to the class's set in `App.css`.

```
// app.css
.test {
  color: red;
}

// app.js
import './app.css';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <App>
        <MyComponent />
      </App>
    );
  }
}

// my-component.js
class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    <div className='test'>
      this text is red.
    </div>
  }
}
```

If you have a css file imported in `MyComponent` that has a style that conflicts with the one passed from `App` then the `MyComponent` style will replace **ALL** uses of the style.

To put in short, *it doesn't matter where your css lives*. Putting css into the same place as components is just way we try to keep things organized but at the end of the day the whole app has access to all css. And from the example we can tell that *latter* definitions of the style replace *earlier* definitions.

Comment: I agree with accessibility for all components but what about structure? do you suggest to put the css definition in each component and for those which are common put them in a closest parent component?

Comment: I think that if it makes sense to you to put them in a parent component, do so. It makes sense to me to do the same but again it's all preference.